# How to extract the file type from a FileStorage Object

Tags: python, flask, types, file-extension, file-storage

```
print(file) 
>> <FileStorage: 'xyz.pdf' ('application/pdf')>
```

How can I extract the file type (extension) from a FileStorage Object?

Comment: can you show your desired output?

Comment: I wanted to use the file type inside an if condition. ```if (file_type == ".pdf"): do something```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for responding. I found the solution.

`file.content_type` gives you the file type for a FileStorage Object

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the [os.path.splitext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function which returns a tuple of the filename and extension:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.splitext('sample.pdf')
('sample', '.pdf')
```

So to extract just the extension from your FileStorage object, simply:

```
_, ext = os.path.splitext(file.filename)
```

This also accounts for file extensions with more than 3 characters, and also filenames with multiple dots; things which could be missed if you manually build a function to do this.